# Is it possible to load a partial view by selecting a Radio Button in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, radio-button

Can i use radio button's to select two different partial view, Without using Jquery?

Comment: More details are needed.

Comment: see updated answer which i think addresses your requirement re no jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes and no. a partial can only be loaded (after initial page load) via ajax, so a partial page refresh isn't possible without using ajax. however, you could `submit` the selected radio button (via javascript) to the controller action and then determine inside the controller which radio button had been selected. It would then just be a case of selecting the appropriate view.

As I said, you can't go down the partial route without ajax in the mix, so the answer is no. also, you'd still have to use javascript in order to use the radio button in the submit, in which case, an ajax solution might be worth thinking about.

**[edit]** with deference to Splash-X, here's a quick work up of the hidden div scenario:

```
@*use either @Html.RenderPartial() or @Html.RenderAction() as required*@

<div id="developerDiv" style="display: none">
    This is the developer stuff, in reality, 
    this would be populated as such @*@Html.RenderPartial("DeveloperPartial")*@
</div>
<div id="testerDiv" style="display: none">
    And here we have the testers, again, 
    this would be populated as such @*@Html.RenderPartial("TestersPartial")*@
</div>
<div>
    Developer :@Html.RadioButton("team", "developer", new { onclick = "showResult(this)"}) 
    Tester :@Html.RadioButton("team", "tester", new { onclick = "showResult(this)"})
</div>
<div id="partialContainer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showResult(radio) {
        var selected = radio.value;
        if (selected == "developer")
            document.getElementById("partialContainer").innerHTML 
                = document.getElementById("developerDiv").innerHTML;
        else if (selected == "tester")
            document.getElementById("partialContainer").innerHTML 
                = document.getElementById("testerDiv").innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

enjoy..

Comment: I am sorry i meant without Jquery

Comment: ahh -ok, that's slightly different, tho the answer remains the same :). you can use javascript on the radio button onClick event. don't have any 'real' examples to hand as jquery seems to be ubiquitious now. this may give clues however: http://www.codeave.com/javascript/code.asp?u_log=7048

Comment: This isn't fully true. Any view can be rendered as part of another view by using the Html Helpers for Html.Partial and Html.RenderPatial. You can include two partial views on a page, both in hidden containers such as a div, and based on the selected value you can toggle the visibility of the partial view.

Comment: Splash - good point (based on the OP's revised question), you'd then just use the javascript DOM functions to show/hide the appropriate div. go for it in an answer ;) i guess the only 'grolly' is cross-browser compatability when not using jquery/prototype etc

Comment: splash-x, i owe you!! will take a wander round your profile ;)

Comment: @jimtollan your answer is very helpful to me, but if you refresh the page the pre-selected value is being selected again, can you suggest a solution for it.

Comment: hi Findings - unfortunately, with radio buttons and selectlists, a page refresh often still retains the previously selected values. I'm not quite sure on the best way for you to overcome this as it's a universal situation. I'll have a ponder... and get back if i stumble on a solution to this 2nd part